# Tools or workflow for site with files behind web root or on other servers

Tags: dreamweaver

I'm about to walk into a project that will have files (mostly PHP) behind web root. I traditionally use Dreamweaver CS4 for development.  For upload I'll do a hybrid of Dreamweaver  and manual FTP.  As a site gets larger and more complex keeping files straight by hand becomes painful (and dangerous) very quickly.

If you are facing similar issues, what are you using?  What is the best way to handle this sort of thing?  It'd be great if DW was aware of the idea of placing files behind web root, but there doesn't seem to be a way to handle this elegantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you might want to check out revision control like Subversion. It does a very good job handling your changes and deploying it to the appropriate server (staging/production). You can even find fairly inexpressive solutions that will do it all for you (meaning once you make a change and send your changes to Subversion /commit/ then Subversion will send them to your sever automatically (or you can do it manually with  a click of a button). You can also use Subversion for free, but then you would have to set it up yourself.

The only problem that I see -- I dont think that Dreamweaver CS4 does not support the latest version of Subversion.

You can also check out Git

I hope that helps.

Comment: Never thought of using version control to maintain server files like that. Do the big boys do it this way?  I mean, when a Facebook needs to deploy an update, what's the workflow?

Comment: I dont know how Facebook does it, but using revision control is a common practice. In fact, I have not see developers not using revision control.

Comment: I've always used revision control to manage local development.  I never thought of it as a tool to deploy and maintain live code to a production web server.

Comment: Check out codesion.com or beanstalkapp.com so get a better idea of how that works and how much it costs.